# curl: argument list too long

Tags: bash, curl, sparkpost

I want to send an email with attached pdf file through the Sparkpost API with curl post.

To insert the pdf I use (my test.pdf is ~ 200KB)

```
"data":"'$(cat test.pdf} | base64 --wrap=0)'"
```

But somehow this doesn't work out showing the following error:

```
/usr/bin/curl: Die Argumentliste ist zu lang (original)
/usr/bin/curl: Argument list is too long
```

EDIT:
curl command

```
curl -X POST https://api.eu.sparkpost.com/api/v1/transmissions -H 'Authorization: <APIKEY>' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
   "options":{
      "open_tracking":false,
      "click_tracking":false,
      "inline_css":false
   },
   "recipients":[
      {
         "address":{
            "email":"user@domain.tld",
            "name":"user"
         }
      }
   ],
   "content":{
      "from":{
         "name":"sender",
         "email":"sender@domain.tld"
      },
      "reply_to":"replyto@domain.tld",
      "subject":"subject",
      "text":"textbody",
      "attachments":[
         {
            "name":"attachmentname.pdf",
            "type":"application/pdf",
            "data":"'$(cat test.pdf | base64 --wrap=0)'"
         }
      ]
   }
}'
```

Comment: Could you post the cURL command you are using?

Comment: @Marcus added my curl command

Answer (score 77, accepted):

This is coming up because you are trying to pass the entirety of the base64'd content on the command line. `curl` has the ability to load in data to POST from a file, which I'd recommend doing. More information can be found in [the man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d), but the basic format is this:

```
curl -X POST -d @filename.txt https://website.com/path
```

Comment: A summary on why the `@` usage directly in your answer would be nice, since it's the only missing part without a clear usage indication.

Comment: Note: Unnecessary use of `-X` ... POST is already inferred. `POST` too [man curl](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/curl.1.html)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144479/what-does-the-at-symbol-before-a-filename-mean-in-a-curl-command

Comment: To make @Alwyn reference more clear, it points to the explanation of the @ "If you start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a filename"

Answer (score 2):

According to the curl manual, the -F option allows you to encode a file for base64, but limits the output to 76 characters.
Ex:
-F '=@localfile;encoder=base64'

Comment: can you givfe full example?

Comment: Yep!
Considering that I am in / home / centos and that sending the names.txt file would use the following command:

curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:1880/test '-F' = @ localfile; encoder = base64 '

However, if the file encoding exceeds 76 characters, the file will be corrupted.