# Form data submission works from POSTMAN but not in PHP or Curl

Tags: php, curl, base64, form-data

I have API backend that accepts base64 of PDF and parses it. The API works in postman. The HTTP request as below, that works well:

```
POST /convert HTTP/1.1
Host: 1.1.1.1:7000
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

data=JVBERi0xLjMKJcTl8uXrp/Og0MTGCjQgMCBvYmoKPDwgL0xlbmd0aCA1IDAgUiAvRmlsdGVyIC9GbGF0ZURlY29kZSA+Pg...SHORTENED FOR READABILITY....MDE3OTg1TMxMTNiYjAyNWI0NWRmZDhkZmE+IF0gPj4Kc3RhcnR4cmVmCjE4NDkxMwolJUVPRgo=
```

However, when the same is done via PHP as below, it returns 500 error.:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://1.1.1.1:7000/convert",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "data=JVBERi0xLjM...4Kc3RhcnR4cmVmCjE4NDkxMwolJUVPRgo%3D",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  ),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
print_r($response);
```

Curl from the terminal executed via shell script throws argument list too long error. What could be possibly wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [curl: argument list too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54090784/curl-argument-list-too-long)

Comment: could you check your php error log file to see more details.

Comment: Not really, as I need data posted to be form data.

Comment: You need to post an assoc array as postfields. Then you can eliminate the Content-Type header.