# argument list too long curl

Tags: bash, curl

Trying to solve "argument list too long"
I have been searching for a solution and found the closest one to my issue
[curl: argument list too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54090784/curl-argument-list-too-long)
however the response is not clear as I am still having the issue "argument list too long"

```
curl -X POST -d @data.txt \
   https://Path/to/attachments  \
   -H 'content-type: application/vnd.api+json' \
   -H 'x-api-key: KEY' \
-d '{
"data": {
  "type": "attachments",
  "attributes": {
    "attachment": {
    "content": "'$(cat data.txt | base64 --wrap=0)'",
    "file_name": "'"$FileName"'"
    }
  }
}
}'
```

thank you

Comment: Yeah, the answer there could use some fleshing out. Basically, you need handle the second block of data the same way as the first: put it in a file, then use `-d @filename` to tell `curl` to read it from that file.

Comment: Useless `cat` do `base64 --wrap=0 <data.txt` instead

Comment: Per the linked answer "_you are trying to pass the entirety of the base64'd content on the command line_". This is a limitation of the shell, not `curl`. The recommendation is "_curl has the ability to load in data to POST from a file_".
Write the json data to some file `/tmp/data` then pass that file path to `curl` using `@` so `curl` knows it's a file path, `curl -d @/tmp/data ...`. `curl` will read data from the file `/tmp/data`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `jq` to format your base64 encoded data string into a proper JSON string, and then pass the JSON data as standard input to the `curl` command.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

attached_file='img.png'

# Pipe the base64 encoded content of attached_file
base64 --wrap=0 "$attached_file" |
# into jq to make it a proper JSON string within the
# JSON data structure
jq --slurp --raw-input --arg FileName "$attached_file" \
'{
  "type": "attachments",
  "attributes": {
    "attachment": {
      "content": .,
      "file_name": $FileName
    }
  }
}
' |
# Get the resultant JSON piped into curl
# that will read the data from the standard input
# using -d @-
curl -X POST -d @- \
   'https://Path/to/attachments'  \
   -H 'content-type: application/vnd.api+json' \
   -H 'x-api-key: KEY'
```

Answer (score 2):

Per [the linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54091092/471376)

> you are trying to pass the entirety of the base64'd content on the command line

This is a limitation of the shell, not `curl`. That is, the shell is responding with error `argument list too long`. The program `curl` is never even started.

The recommendation is

> curl has the ability to load in data to POST from a file

1. Write the json data to some file `/tmp/data.json` using piping.
   (the commands will use piping `|` and file redirection `>` `>>` which can handle arbitrarily large amounts of data. Whereas, [you cannot place arbitrarily large amounts of data into a single command, there is a limit](https://serverfault.com/questions/163371/linux-command-line-character-limit)).

```sh
echo -n '
{
"data": {
  "type": "attachments",
  "attributes": {
    "attachment": {
    "content": "' > /tmp/data.json

cat data.txt | base64 --wrap=0 >> /tmp/data.json

echo -n '",
    "file_name": "'"$FileName"'"
    }
  }
}
}' >> /tmp/data.json
```

2. Pass that file path `/tmp/data.json` to the `curl` command using `@` so curl knows it's a file path.

```sh
curl -X POST -d @/tmp/data.json \
   "https://Path/to/attachments"  \
   -H 'content-type: application/vnd.api+json' \
   -H 'x-api-key: KEY'
```