# Convert log files to base64 and upload it using Curl to Github

Tags: json, bash, github, curl, github-api

I am trying to upload a file to Github using its API.

Following code works, but only with smaller size content which is approx less than 1MB.

```
tar -czvf logs.tar.gz a.log b.log
base64_logs=$(base64 logs.tar.gz | tr -d \\n)

content_response=$(curl \
  -X PUT \
  -u :"$GIT_TOKEN" \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  "$content_url" \
  -d '{"message": "Log files", "content": "'"$base64_logs"'"}')
```

For content that is a bit large, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/curl: Argument list too long
```

Now, there is already a question on SO about this error message, and it says that to upload a file directly. See here: [curl: argument list too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54090784/curl-argument-list-too-long)

When I try this, I get a `problem parsing JSON` error message.

```
tar -czvf logs.tar.gz a.log b.log
base64_logs=$( base64 logs.tar.gz | tr -d \\ ) > base64_logs.txt

content_response=$(curl \
  -X PUT \
  -u :"$GIT_TOKEN" \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  "$content_url" \
  -d '{"message": "Log files", "content": @base64_logs.txt}')
```

Can anyone point me out where I am making mistake here? Thanks!

Comment: `jq -n '{"message": "Log files", "content": ($content | @base64)}' --rawfile content yourfilehere`

Comment: replacing line with `-d $( jq -n '{"message": "Log files", "content": ($content | @base64)}' --rawfile content logs.tar.gz )` returns `argument list too long` error.

Comment: Curl is complaining argument list too long because the generated JSON length exceeds the arguments buffer length and because without double quotes around the sub-shell expansion it splits at spaces into multiple arguments. Basically: `jq -n '{"message": "Log files", "content": ($content | @base64)}' --rawfile content logs.tar.gz | curl --data-binary @- ...`

Comment: Seems it is uploading but when I try to open the uploaded content it gives the following message `tar: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format`. By any chance is it corrupting the content?

Comment: jq @base64 is only capable of encoding text, and not binary data like a gz archive. So instead of encoding base64 with Jq do it with the base64 command instead. Ill make this an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `base64` command rather than the `@base64` filter from `jq`, because the later can only encode textual data and not binary data as from a `.gz` archive.

Pipe the base64 stream to `jq` to format it into a JSON data stream.

Curl will read the JSON data stream and send it.

```sh
# use base64 to encode binary data and -w0 all in one-line stream
base64 --wrap=0 logs.tar.gz |

# JSON format from raw input
jq \
  --raw-input \
  --compact-output \
  '{"message": "Log files", "content": . }' |

# Pipe JSON to curl
curl \
  --request PUT \
  --user ":$GIT_TOKEN" \
  --header "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data-binary @- \
  --url "$content_url"
```